# Explain implementation of function call operator in boost value_factory

Tags: c++11, templates, factory, member-functions, boost-functional

I am trying to understand the boost implementation of factory design pattern. Boost provides two types of factory one for pointer types and other for value semantics. I am able to understand a little about the template value_factory class. However I am facing difficulty is understanding how `operator()(..)` is defined outside class and namespace.

Below is the link to complete code: https://github.com/boostorg/functional/blob/7516442815900430cc9c4a6190354e11bcbe72dd/include/boost/functional/value_factory.hpp

Code snippet after removing lot of includes.

```
#   ifndef BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING
namespace boost
{
    template< typename T >  class value_factory;

    template< typename T >
    class value_factory
    {
      public:
        typedef T result_type;
        value_factory()
        { }
    }; // value_factory
    
    template< typename T > class value_factory<T&>;
} // namespace boost
#   else // defined(BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING)
    template< BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(0, typename T) >
    inline result_type operator()(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS(0, T, &a)) const
    {
        return result_type(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(N,a));
    }
#   endif // defined(BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING)
```

This code is from boost version 1.71.

I would like to understand how `operator()(...)` plays role here

1. It is outside class
2. It is defined in 2nd conditional block `#   else // defined(BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING)`

As per my understanding member function `operator()(...)` should have been inside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* defined inside the class. The trick is that the header file is including itself and is using macro-magic to eventually terminate the recursion.

The end of the class definition has this `#include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()` line and it will recursively `#include` itself until `BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING` is `#define`d. The result of that inclusion t will go where marked:

```cpp
#     define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_1 <boost/functional/value_factory.hpp>
#     define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_LIMITS (0,BOOST_FUNCTIONAL_VALUE_FACTORY_MAX_ARITY)
#     include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()              // <- operator() definition goes here

    }; // end of class [my remark]

    template< typename T > class value_factory<T&>;
    // forbidden, would create a dangling reference

} // namespace boost [my remark]

#     define BOOST_FUNCTIONAL_VALUE_FACTORY_HPP_INCLUDED
#   else // defined(BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING)

// the operator definition in header
```

If compiled with `g++ -E` you can also see the result:

```cpp
namespace boost {

template<class T>
class value_factory;

template<class T>
class value_factory {
public:
    typedef T result_type;



    template<class... Args>
    result_type operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        return result_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
# 99 "/home/ted/local/include/boost/functional/value_factory.hpp"
};

template<class T>
class value_factory<T&> { };

}
```